# .htaccess deny access from external request

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to limit the access for some pages in my web site. I have some BL pages in PHP and I want to limit thier access to only internal access.

I mean that I want that these pages will be denied if the user type them in the browser, but will be accessible if another PHP page will call them (with POST or GET requests).

Is it possible to do that in the .htaccess file?
If it is, how?

Comment: By "**another PHP page will call them**", do you mean another php page links to them via an `<a href` or something? Or do you mean call them through the script like `require protected.php`?

Comment: Send POST or GET requests. `require` will work even if the pages are not in the public folder..

Comment: So you are going to use something like the cURL library to make an HTTP request to localhost? That doesn't seem very efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clarify, the php page isn't the one sending POST or GET request, it's the *browser*, which means you can't block by IP. So you need to be checking against the referer here. Problem with that is the referer can be easily forged so this is no guarantee that you'll be denying access.

You can check the referer using the `%{HTTP_REFERER}` variable in mod_rewrite and then use the `F` flag to deny access:

```
RewriteEngine On
# if the request's referer isn't from a php page on your site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://your-domain.com/.*\.php
# deny access to the list of php files
RewriteRule ^(path/to/protected.php|path/another_protected.php|images/protected.png)$ - [L,F]
```

Answer (score -1):

you can restrict by user agent.. but it's not the better way...

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  (Chrome|Firefox|Webkit)
 RewriteRule .* -
```

if you know from where the request come from just add

```
Order allow deny
Allow from xx.xx.xxx.xx/xx
deny from all
```

sorry the poor english

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but don't do this! A hacker can spoof the user agent! Added concern is that this doesn't even work with more obscure browser like w3m.