# FilesMatch or Files in htaccess to deny two specific files

Tags: .htaccess

I mostly understand using Files for one file and FileMatch for broad regex matching, but if I wanted to deny access to two or three specific unique files how would I best do that?

Ideas:

```
<Files .htpasswd>
   Order allow,deny
   Deny from all
   Satisfy All 
</Files> 

<Files htpasswd-example>
   Order allow,deny
   Deny from all
   Satisfy All 
</Files> 

<Files htaccess-example>
   Order allow,deny
   Deny from all
   Satisfy All 
</Files>
```

or something like:

```
<FilesMatch "^(.htpasswd|htpasswd-example|htaccess-example)$">
   Order allow,deny
   Deny from all
   Satisfy All 
</FilesMatch>
```

note: unrelated but I can't make these example files . files for other reasons, hence my desire to hide them.

Comment: Isn't `FilesMatch` working for you?

Comment: Sorry my question wasn't as concise as it could have been. Ultimately I'm wondering "what is the best way to do this" but I'm also "is there a way to use multiple files in the Files directive. ie. <Files ".htpasswd|htpassword-example|htaccess-example".  The FilesMatch directive I literally just typed up here on SO, hadn't even tried it since I wasn't sure my RegEx was correct or it was really the best way.

Comment: Give it a try with FilesMatch and see if that works as regex looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost$ [NC] 
 RewriteRule ^ - [L,F]
```

So, if the host is other than "localhost" deny it.
Check out this answer too:
[.htaccess deny access from external request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21454371/htaccess-deny-access-from-external-request)

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to block all external requests. I just want to block access to these specific files.

Comment: check the link i posted

Comment: When posting a link as an answer on SO it's best to summarize specifically what you're referring to.